# ESLint indentation issue with commented lines

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

There is an indentation issue with comment lines. To give an clear idea please take look on the following screenshot with descriptions.

In my VS code I have configured to Auto saved with ESLint formatting.

In here I have two commented lines of code. (line 49 and 50) with proper indentation.
[image]

And then when I save the page, starting from line 47 to 57 (the code block which contains the commented code) indentation become like the below screenshot.
[image]

Even after the fixing these issue, it continuously happens.

UPDATE:
With comment lines
[image]

Without comment lines

[image]

Comment: Need more information my man. What does the error say when you hover over the red squiggles? (you can also check the error message in your problems view)

Comment: @jD3V There is no error messages. It happens on save please take look I have added new another screenshot.